# Display Camera View With Custom UI

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-camera

Good day android geniuses! I am creating an application that allows the user to use the their android phone as speedometer. Imagine the phone posted to the top of your windshield. The phone should be using the camera view without any of the stock UI with a speedometer in the right hand corner. I am currently using intents to display the camera but this displays a camera with all the stock UI. How can i display the camera view with a custom UI overlay?

Answer (score 1):

some quick googling shows this result here http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html  This example is older, but its the concept that matters here..

you cannot start your camera with an intent if you want a custom ui, you have to create the custom ui and initialize the camera all yourself.